# What version of Ubuntu should I use?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I have a Toshiba laptop running Window XP (32) about 10 or 12 years old.  It is used at a model railroad club and its sole function is to run Java and an open source program called Decoder Pro.  It works great for our purposes but is getting dated as it no longer accepts updates.  I would like to use Ubuntu.  Which version should I use, etc.?

Comment: Check [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/q/206407); I'd recommend a lightweight variant of Ubuntu, such as [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) or [Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/), and use the latest version (16.04).

Comment: I second @JonasCz ... you might not be aware that mainstream Ubuntu is *considering* not producing 32 bit version in the future.

Answer (score 0):

On older machine like this you would be better to use a lighter version of Ubuntu like [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) or [Kubuntu](http://kubuntu.org/), these distributions will require less resources to run. I'm pretty sure your machine is a **32-bit** machine so you would need a **32-bit ISO** if it's a **64-bit** then you would use a **64-bit** ISO file to get things rolling

Here's a quick guide if you need help you with your installation
[How to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop)

Comment: It is probably a 32bit machine, but even if it had a 64bit CPU, I would still recommend a 32bit OS unless it has more than at least 2-4 GB RAM. And Kubuntu is definitely not a lightweight distribution. I would rather recommend Xubuntu (XFCE desktop) instead.

Comment: Recommended
1 GB of RAM.
Better than 1 GHz (x86) or Dual Core processor.
10 GB of hard-drive space or SSD (the more hard disk capacity, the better)
VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution.